# Click on the button red dot should blink

Tags: java, javafx

I have a fontawesomeicon. If I press the button `btStar`t a red circle should flash on the Fontawesomeicon (see GIF). If I press the button `btStop` it should be disabled.
I tried it with a label.
When I press the button btStart, the label changes in a time interval with `SetVisible(true)` and `setVisible(false)`.

[image]

Can someone offer me a solution? Thank you in advance.
Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;

import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import java.awt.*;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private FontAwesomeIconView iconCamera;

    @FXML
    private Button btStart;

    @FXML
    private Button btStop;

    @FXML
    void mouseCklicked(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("sad");

    }
}
```

sample.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>


<GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <columnConstraints>
      <ColumnConstraints />
   </columnConstraints>
   <rowConstraints>
      <RowConstraints />
   </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="387.0" prefWidth="573.0">
         <children>
            <FontAwesomeIconView fx:id="iconCamera" glyphName="VIDEO_CAMERA" layoutX="130.0" layoutY="123.0" size="36" />
            <Button layoutX="253.0" layoutY="93.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#mouseCklicked" text="Start" />
            <Button layoutX="354.0" layoutY="93.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stop" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Create an Image (PNG) without the red dot.
- Create a GIF with the red dot blinking effect.
- Import both images in to your project.
- On pressing the start set the image to *.GIF.
- On pressing stop set the image to *.PNG.

Simple. Don't make things complicated!

Comment: I'd recommend creating an image/SVG for the camera (black part) only instead and using a `Timeline` to display/hide a red circle. This way you don't need to create multiple images. Additionally you can programatically adjust the blink rate easily...

Comment: @fabian Drawing a red circle is not a problem, but how do I get the red circle to the exact spot?
And why pictures when I have an icon?

Comment: And how do I make the circle blink with `TimeLine` ?

Comment: @JoeMau You don't want a `TimeLine` at all.